# Dask distributed ImportError: Please 'pip install zict' with Python 2.7 on Centos 7

Tags: dask

Installed dask with "pip install dask[complete] distributed --upgrade" Python 2.7 on Centos 7.
Running:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client() # set up local cluster
print client
```

Getting:

> Process Process-1: Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in
>   _bootstrap self.run() File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
>   self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs) File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/process.py", line 181,
>   in _run target(*args, **kwargs) File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/nanny.py", line 587, in
>   _run worker = Worker(*worker_args, **worker_kwargs) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 479, in
>   **init** raise ImportError("Please `pip install zict` for spill-to-disk workers") ImportError: Please `pip install zict` for
>   spill-to-disk workers

zict is already installed on the system

Please Help

Update: Looks like "pip install zict==1.*" (after removing zict v2) fixed the problem. Is it the correct way to go?

Comment: Probably you are falling foul of dask dropping support for py2. It may be that zict's requirements have not been updated.

Comment: If you have a working solution, please post as an answer